# Windows CE Silverlight Setup

Tags: windows-ce, silverlight-embedded

I have an embedded device,its includes windows CE 6.0 Build 3112.I want to run silverlight application on this device.I downloaded silverlight application,when I want to install it says "Silverlight is not valid application windows CE"

so what can i do?
Thx.

Comment: Member for 1 year, asked 9 questions, not accepted any of them, whats that all about?

Comment: You are sure that the app in question has been written to be installed on Embedded?

Comment: Why don't you mark something as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Addition to [ctacke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554101/windows-ce-silverlight-setup/2557637#2557637). Not all Windows CE devices have to have any specific component and that includes Silverlight for Embedded Devices.
To check whether your device includes Silverlight For Embedded devices, you can check whether your `\Windows` folder contains the `xamlruntime.dll` file. If it does not contain the file, then your OEM did not include Silverlight in the image.

If you want to check out a simple Silverlight for Embedded devices application you can download the code from the following tutorial: [Silverlight for Embedded Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210122073003/http://geekswithblogs.net/WindowsEmbeddedCookbook/archive/2009/10/01/silverlight-for-embedded-tutorial.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

THe issue you're seeing is that while it's *called* "Silverlight", [Silverlight for Windows Embedded](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products/windowsce/silverlightforwe.mspx) really isn't what most developers who know Silverlight would call Silverlight (in fact I wish they'd rename it).

While it does use XAML and that XAML can be created using Blend, the code itself has to be written in heavily templated C++.  You can't take a compiled Silverlight binary from anything other platform and use it under CE.